# Given a total perimeter, how can I solve for side lengths?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I've been given a shape with perimeter $p$, in the case of the below shape, $52$.

[image]

How can I calculate the lengths of the shortest, middle, and longest sides? I'm totally stuck, so any help or hints are very much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Express the value of the perimeter in two ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perimeter is the sum of all the sides of a shape. In this case, the perimeter is 
$$(7x-4) + (10x+3) + 19$$
 $$7x - 4 + 10x + 3 + 19$$
$$18 + 17x$$
Since we know the perimeter is 52, set these equal
$$18 + 17x = 52$$
$$34 = 17x$$
$$x = 2$$
From here we can calculate the three sides. One is of length 19, the other is of length $[10x+3] = [20+3] = 24$, and the other is of length $[7x-4] = [14-4] = 10$